# fastest way to operate on a dataframe - write the output onto two new columns

Tags: r, dataframe

OK, it may not be the best title. I am trying to optimize my script to make it run fast. Let me give you an example input and an example output:

```
mydf<- data.frame('col1'=c('firstresult01anotherresult02','firstresult03anotherresult04'))
```

I can write a custom function that extracts the info from `col1`, such as I get something like: `'result01'` and `'result02'` from the first row, and `'result03'` and `'result04'` from the second row. Next, I would like to put the output from each row on a different column, such as the output dataframe would be:

```
        mydf<- data.frame('col1'=c('firstresult01anotherresult02',
         'thirdresult03fourthresult04'), 'col2' = c('result01', 'result03'),
         'col3'=c('result02', 'result04'))
```

You can notice that the first output string from each row went on 'col2' and the second output string of each went on 'col3'.

If I only had one output string I could do something like:

```
mydf$col2<- sapply(x = mydf$col1, FUN = my_custom_function)
```

Since I will have 2 output strings to go into two separate columns, I either repeat the operation twice (probably the fastest option), or I subset by row, each time assigning the values to the two new columns. I wonder if there is a more elegant solution to do this. Please let me know if the example is not clear, I look forward to here from you all :)

Comment: It's probably a better idea to extract to a long form like `library(tidyverse); mydf %>% mutate(col2 = stringr::str_extract_all(col1, 'result\\d+')) %>% unnest()`; add another column for indices if necessary.

Comment: Alistaire, thank you. Also for introducing me to the '%>%' operator, looks really interesting.
I am not sure if I am interpreting your solution in the right way: would that still imply to run the operation twice? I'll have a look at the tidyverse library first

Comment: Another way i found to do it would be to store the results from each row in a character vector. That would allow me to go through each row only once using 'sapply'; then create a column ; then create the new columns using every other element from the character vector (either odd or even indexes). Hope it makes sense. But  I had a quick look at the tidyverse, I definitely need to go back to it as soon as I have some time, thank you for the advice

Comment: `str_extract_all` returns a list, which `mutate` adds as a column. At this point each initial string is now associated with a character vector, which is stored in the new column. `unnest` expands the list column, repeating the `col1` value as necessary.